# How to calculate rotationDegree for fillPatternImage of wedges?

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry, kineticjs, trigonometry

I have the following circle, made of wedges. Each wedge has a *fillPatternImage*. Each *fillPatternImage* has an image with a centered text. The text varies in length for each wedge.

The problem is I need to give each *fillPatternImage* a rotation degree so all text aligns perfectly along the circle’s perimeter. But I have no clue what rotation degree to give each *fillPatternImage*.

For example, when I give all *fillPatternImages* a rotation degree of 95°, short texts align well, but long texts turn out crooked.

I suppose rotation degree must be dynamic for each *fillPatternImage*. But I haven’t found out how. I have the wedge dimensions, the text width, etc.

[image]

Code example for fillPatternImage:

```
imageObj.src = Caption + ".png";
imageObj.onload = function () {
    nts.setFillPatternImage(imageObj);
    nts.setFillPatternRotationDeg(95);
    // nts.setFillPatternOffset(-220, 100);
    nts.setFillPatternX(radio - 15);
    nts.setFillPatternY(leftSide);
    nts.setFillPatternRepeat("no-repeat");
    nts.draw();
}
```

Any ideas would be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: would if you can make a jsfiddle out of it so people can tinker with it. It helps to solve problems like these I think

Comment: Sorry, part of the project is runnung on Rails because images are being generated with RMagick. A JsFiddle would require refactoring major part of the code.

Comment: Are your texts part of the image or are they kinetic.Text?  The solution is easier if text is not part of the image.  Either way, you will need to know the font size and font face.

Comment: @markE: Text parts are part of the image. I do know the fonts size and font face, though I don't know how to achieve the above effect with kinetic text.

Comment: I'd come back to this problem which is still unanswered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826393/how-to-draw-text-kineticjs-inside-wedge-in-circular-menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to calculate fillPatternRotation angle for a Kinetic Wedge**

[image]

Your text will always be appropriately rotated in the Kinetic wedge with this fillPatternRotation:

```
  fillPatternRotation:Math.PI/2+wedgeAngleDeg*Math.PI/360
```

Where wedgeAngleDeg is the value supplied to wedge.angleDeg:

```
  angleDeg: wedgeAngleDeg
```

You also need to set the appropriate wedge fillPatternOffset to match your text-image

[image]

You must horizontally offset the fillPattern to the midpoint of the text on the image

Assuming your text is horizontally centered on your image, that offset is image.width/2.

```
 fillPatternOffset X is image.width/2
```

You must vertically offset the fillPattern to align the image text to the largest width on the wedge.

You can calculate the largest wedge width like this:

```
 var textTop=radius*Math.sin(wedgeAngleDeg*Math.PI/180);
```

So your fillPatternOffset becomes:

```
 fillPatternOffset: [image.width/2, image.height-textTop],
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Y53cH/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script defer="defer">

      var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
      });

      var img=new Image();
      img.onload=function(){
          start();
      }
      img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/testing.png";

      function start(){

          var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

          var wedgeAngleDeg=60;
          var radius=100;
          var textTop=radius*Math.sin(wedgeAngleDeg*Math.PI/180);

          var wedge = new Kinetic.Wedge({
            x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
            y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
            radius: radius,
            angleDeg: wedgeAngleDeg,
            fillPatternImage: img,
            fillPatternOffset: [img.width/2, img.height-textTop],
            fillPatternRepeat:"no-repeat", 
            fillPatternRotation:Math.PI/2+wedgeAngleDeg*Math.PI/360,       
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 4,
            rotationDeg: 0
          });
          layer.add(wedge);

          wedge.setRotationDeg(-45);

          // add the layer to the stage
          stage.add(layer);

      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer is exactly what the doctor ordered markE. I can't thank you enough. It's still sunday, hope you enjoy it and have a fantastic week. Greetings from Mexico.